# Are Java EE server components compiled?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, compiler-construction

Does the server or container do any kind of compiling of resusable objects or components for faster execution?

Comment: What 'components' are you referring to?

Comment: I think I said resubable objects also. Any component that might benefit from compiling...a java bean, an EJB. I think you know.

Comment: So you're asking for application components - for your code, your classes? Well, you need to compile them in order to deploy them in the application server. You're deploying byte-code files, not source-files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not about compiling, therefore I'm not sure if it helps:
Java EE servers for example maintain pools of database connections or stateless EJBs for reuse.

Comment: I wonder what they're executing. intermediate code? Some type of compiling must go on.

Comment: In the end Java Byte code is executed. But the compiling takes place before you deploy the application on the server. JSPs are an exception. They are converted to Java code by the server and compiled after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

By default, any recent Java VM will do just-in-time compilation of frequently used program code which translates the intermediate Java bytecode to native code on the underlying platform. This usually boosts performance of those code parts. When and if Java bytecode will be compiled to native is at the discretion of the VM.